# showAlertBox() not waiting for response

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a .jsp file in which I have two functions..

```
function killIt()
{
    if(peopleCount==1)
    {

        showYesNoPopupBox("Kill It", "There is only one person.. Are you sure you want to kill it?" , function(resp){
            if(resp)
            {
                kill();
            }
        } );
    }
    else
    {
        kill();
    }
}

function kill()
{
        if(personIds == "")
        {
            showAlertBox("Kill it", "Select at least one person to kill...");
            return false;
        }
    //code to kill person...
}
```

The jsp file displays in rows checkbox and personID.
peopleCount is the total number of people that are displayed and personIds will have the personID of the rows that are selected.

What I want is, if there is only one person, the page should display a warning msg that there is only one person. So do you want to kill it. Only on confirmation, it should call kill(). 
Otherwise, if there are more than one persons, it should call the kill().

In kill() it first checks. If there are no persons selected (if no checkbox is ticked) , then it will show an alert msg to select atleast one person to kill.

When I executed my code, it is working fine when the peopleCount is not 1.

When peopleCount is not 1, and when I dont select any checkbox and click on kill button, then it shows the warning `"Select at least one person to kill..."` and waits for me to click ok. But when peopleCount is 1, it shows the warning msg `" There is only one person.. Are you sure you want to kill it?"`. Then when I press `"Proceed"`, it shows the alert msg `"Select at least one person to kill..."` and stops immediately without waiting for me to click ok on the alert window.

Why is it not waiting for me to press OK ?

Note- on clicking kill button, killIt() will be called.

Comment: Where is `personIds` populated?

Comment: I have a table "Person" in jbossdb which has personIDs.. `personIds`  is a var in jsp file. `var personIds = getSelectedCheckBoxValue("personChkBox");`